# ubuntu-gnome 16.04.1 Icons dissapeared!

Tags: gnome, icons, ubuntu-gnome

I don't know why after a software upgrade all icons have disappeared. (on/off, wifi, battery, volume, brightness, even the crosses to close the windows). The mouse accuracy also changed, but I managed to solve that. You can see I'm a beginner in Ubuntu, so I appreciate any help.

Sorry if the question is already answered but I couldn't find any solution.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You've already tried a reboot, yes?

Comment: Yes, in the login screen the icons appear.